# Can a Native Thread Block a Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have two threads running in a thread pool. My application just hangs after I run it. I can see in thread dump that one thread is in MONITOR, and the other is in RUNNING state. 
The thread in RUNNING state shows that it entered a synchronized method and acquired lock, and finally called a native method, and stopped responding. But it's state shows RUNNING.
The second thread in MONITOR state is blocked waiting for first thread to release MONITOR. My suspiscion is, that the two two threads are deadlocked, although the thread dump shows that the first thread is RUNNING. I suspect it is trying to acquire some monitor from native code which the thread stack cannot show. Is it possible that the thread in native call, and the Java thread are deadlocked? See below.
One more thing. If I repeatedly run the app, 'deadlocks' like above explained occur randomly at various parts of code and not just what is pasted below.. usually between Java and Native, and sometimes between native and native on File IO operations (which is understandable). But can a Java and Native go into deadlock? Thanks.

```
"pool-1-thread-2@4640" prio=5 tid=0x14 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     blocks pool-1-thread-1@4641
      at java.lang.Object.clone(Object.java:-1)
      at java.util.ResourceBundle$CacheKey.clone(ResourceBundle.java:655)
      at java.util.ResourceBundle.putBundleInCache(ResourceBundle.java:1693)
      at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1477)
      at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1361)
      at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.SecuritySupport$7.run(SecuritySupport.java:169)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.SecuritySupport$7.run(SecuritySupport.java:166)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-1)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.SecuritySupport.getResourceBundle(SecuritySupport.java:166)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegexParser.setLocale(RegexParser.java:99)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegexParser.<init>(RegexParser.java:93)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParserForXMLSchema.<init>(ParserForXMLSchema.java:41)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.setPattern(RegularExpression.java:2291)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.setPattern(RegularExpression.java:2308)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.<init>(RegularExpression.java:2266)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl.applyFacets(XSSimpleTypeDecl.java:844)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl.applyFacets1(XSSimpleTypeDecl.java:751)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.BaseSchemaDVFactory.createBuiltInTypes(BaseSchemaDVFactory.java:208)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl.createBuiltInTypes(SchemaDVFactoryImpl.java:47)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SchemaDVFactoryImpl.java:42)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-1)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.ObjectFactory.newInstance(ObjectFactory.java:158)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.ObjectFactory.newInstance(ObjectFactory.java:143)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:73)
      - locked <0x1226> (a java.lang.Class)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:57)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:1027)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:559)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:538)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.XmlProcessor.validateXml(XmlProcessor.java:52)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.XmlProcessor.validateInputXML(XmlProcessor.java:34)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.Controller.processRecord(Controller.java:99)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.Controller.lambda$invokeTransformationService$1(Controller.java:80)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.Controller$$Lambda$29.1090160486.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"pool-1-thread-1@4641" prio=5 tid=0x13 nid=NA waiting for monitor entry
  java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
     waiting for pool-1-thread-2@4640 to release lock on <0x1226> (a java.lang.Class)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:57)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:1027)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:559)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:538)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.XmlProcessor.validateXml(XmlProcessor.java:52)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.XmlProcessor.validateInputXML(XmlProcessor.java:34)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.Controller.processRecord(Controller.java:99)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.Controller.lambda$invokeTransformationService$1(Controller.java:80)
      at com.fmr.feeds.transformation.Controller$$Lambda$29.1090160486.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only through the operating system (e.g. contending for CPU or filesystem resources).

Native code may spin up threads that are not monitored by the JVM, but threads in the JVM can only block - from a language perspective - on other threads that are also managed by the JVM (unless the native code is extremely clever).

It looks like thread `pool-1-thread-2@4640` is currently doing something in your thread-dump. Perhaps waiting for CPU or OS resources. The other thread is waiting for a lock held in that thread's call-stack.